# Prove there are at least m minimum spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, proof-writing, trees

I just encountered a question of the MST:

Assume $G$ is a weighted connected graph, and there is a cycle $C$ of length $m$, and the weights of these $m$ edges are all equal to the minimum value of edge weights in $E(G)$.[ $E(G)$ is the set of the edges. ]

Prove: there are at least $m$ different minimum spanning trees of $G$.

My solution is:

First prove that the minimum spanning tree must contain one of these $m$ least weight edges.

Then assume $T$ contains edge $e_i, i \in \{1,2,\dots, m\}$. Add another edge $e_j,  j \in \{1,2,\dots, m\}, j\neq i$ to the minimum spanning tree $T$.

But I found it difficult in step 2... It seems useless in proving there are at least $m$ different minimum spanning trees.

Comment: Imagine your graph only consisted of nodes in this cycle $C$. How many min-cost spanning trees can you find?

Comment: Well, I suppose there are at least (m+1) nodes in the graph, or there could not be "the least weighted edge". And for (m+1) nodes, we could choose to remove any edge in the cycle $C$ (m edges in total). It satisfies the proof.

Comment: What will be the $m-1$ first weights choose when using Kruskal algorithm? How many non equivalent choices can be made in the $m-1$ first steps ?

Comment: Hmmm... I guess we could follow a reverse order of the algorithm to think about the case of $m+1$ nodes..? We first prove that the algorithms just need $m$ iterations ; then we could find that the last step of the algorithms would be selecting one edge with weight larger than the weight of $m$ edges, or we'll have $m$ edges of the smallest values and thus formulating a cycle in the spanning tree ;

Comment: Then we conclude that there're $m-1$ smallest edges selected in the minimum spanning tree. So, there're $m$ ways to remove $1$ edge from $m$ edge.